# Python3 Opencv error with Hconcat and Vconcat

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

So i was trying out the vconcat and hconcat funktion of OpenCv2 but whenever i run it, it gives me this error.
`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_operations.cpp:65: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].rows == src[0].rows && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'hconcat`

here is the code:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('test1.jpeg')
img2 = cv2.imread('book.jpg')

h_concat_img = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])
v_concat_img = cv2.vconcat([img1, img2])

cv2.imshow('horizontal', h_concat_img)
cv2.imshow('vertical', v_concat_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And i think its only a problem from my site.

Python 3.10.8
Opencv 4.6.0

I was very confused even tried copying "Exactly" what a website told me with the same file name, here is the code

Comment: Did you check the shapes of your images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html)  for `hconcat`:

> All of the matrices must have the same number of rows and the same depth.

Same for `vconcat`:

> All of the matrices must have the same number of cols and the same depth.

Examine `img1.shape` and `img2.shape`. If you still need help, please share your images in your question.

Alternatives what you can do:

- crop the larger image
- extend the smaller image by some colour
- resize the larger and/or the smaller image

Comment: Yeah they arent  the same size, img1 is 982x1398 and img2 is 960x1346. Anyway i can fix it?

Comment: crop one or both images to the same size. See Numpy slicing for doing the crop

Comment: @BodyCreator0909 Added some obvious possibilities how to fix this to my answer.